# How to generate alignments for word-based translation models if number of words are different in both sentences

Tags: python, machine-translation

I am working on implementing IBM Model 1. I have a parallel corpus of some 2,000,000 sentences (English to Dutch). Also, the sentences of the two docs are already aligned. The aim is to translate a Dutch sentence into English and vice-versa.

The code I am using for generating the alignments is:

```py
A = pair_sent[0].split()  # To split English sentence
B = pair_sent[1].split()  # To split Dutch sentence
trips.append([zip(A, p) for p in product(B, repeat=len(A))])
```

Now, there are pair sentences with an unequal number of words (like 10 in English and 14 in its Dutch Translation). Our professor told us that we should use NULLs or drop a word. But I don't understand how to do that? Where to insert NULL and how to choose which word to drop.

In the end, I require the pair of sentences to have the equal number of words.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the sentences have a different number of words. After all, the IBM model computes for each word in a source sentence a probability distribution over all words in the target sentence and does not care how many words the target sentence has. The problem is that there might words that do not have counter-part in the target sentence.

If you append a *NULL* word into the target sentence (no matter where because IBM Model 1 does not consider reordering), you can also model the probability that a word does not have a counter-part in the target sentence.

The actual bilingual alignment is then done using a symmetrization heuristic from a pair of IBM models on both sides.